# Nginx: index mapping

Tags: nginx, tomcat, java

I'm trying to install Nging as a frontend server for HTTP requests but the welcome page does not work:

```
server {
  listen          8081;
  server_name     localhost;
  root            /home/me/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps;
  location ~ \.htm$ {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  }
  #my solution
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  }
}
```

If I call `http://127.0.0.1:8081/myapp/` I got a 403 error.
If I call `http://127.0.0.1:8081/myapp/index.htm` it works.

**index.htm** does not exist: it is a java generated page.

How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:
I have duplicated the location with another mapping to fix it but I don't know if it is a good practice :s

Comment: The `location ~ \.htm$` is useless here, as all requests match `location /` anyway.

Comment: OK but how can I define the welcome page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "index" directive at location section. As Tero said you don't need the .htm location for this setup. Example:

location / {
 index index.htm;
 proxy_pass       ........
}

Optionally you can rename the index file to index.html since it's the default value.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index